# Stopping alarm and alarm ringtone together

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarm

I am developing an alarm app.
When it fires an alarm it throws notification with a disable button.
So when i click on the disable button it should stop the alarm ringtone and the alarm also.

so when i click on disable button it call the below method.
It stops the alarm.
But i want to know will this ringtone alive for next date with same time or it will remove the alarm forgood?

```
public void dismissRingtone() {
    // stop the alarm rigntone
    Intent i = new Intent(this, RingtonePlayingService.class);
    stopService(i);

    // also dismiss the alarm to ring again or trigger again
    AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    aManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    // Canceling the current notification
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager)getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(321);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, it will cancel future alarms.

```
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // Set the alarm for a particular time.

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    try {
        pendingIntent.cancel();
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: But in my code i am canceling the current alarm. But will alarm still be alive for next day? I want to know that

Comment: Broadcast receiver + scheduled pending intents will be cancelled unless you don't schedule again.

Comment: so if i using ur code it will cancel the both. Am i r8.. Thanks :)